# Modifying global variable with same name as local variable

Tags: python, global-variables

Suppose I have a global variable `a`. And within a function definition, we also have a local variable named `a`. Is there any way to assign the value of the global variable to that of the local variable?

```
a = 'foo'

def my_func(a = 'bar'):
    # how to set global a to value of the local a?
```

Comment: use 'global a' statement within the function definition?

Comment: @newtover: But then I can't access the value of the local `a` in order to assign it to the global one.

Comment: `WHY???!!1!11one|11!1ELEVE|\|1!?`. To start, using globals is a bad practice, add a parameter to your func or make a class. Second, why would you want to use the same variable name in different contexts and relate their content. Can you try harder in making your code more ugly and confusing?

Comment: This is exactly why using global variables is discouraged. Even if there is a way to do this, you shouldn't do it. Change the local variable name, or -- better yet -- don't use a global variable.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: I'm asking this to better understand the language (all aspects of it, not just "best practices").

Comment: A bit late to the party, but whenever I hit the local/global collision issue, I use an empty class as a namespace container (`class Container(): pass`, `settings = Container()`, `settings.a = 'foo'`) and store my global variables in there. It's both mutable and distinguishable: `if var1 is None: var1 = settings.var1`, `else: settings.var1 = var1` and so on.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Use [built-in function `globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals).

> **`globals()`**
>
> *Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol
>   table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a
>   function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the
>   module from which it is called).*

```
a = 'foo'

def my_func(a = 'bar'):
    globals()['a'] = a
```

BTW, it's worth mentioning that a global is only "global" within the scope of a module.

Comment: Can you explain more on the note you provided that "global is only "global" within the scope of a module" by detailing what is a module here?

Comment: @SaurabhSaha typically single file. Module, as in something that can be `import`-ed https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Thanks @vartec. It would mean we can have global variables with the same name in different modules.

Answer (score 2):

Don't muddle global and local namespaces to begin with. Always try and use a local variable versus a global one when possible. If you must share variables between scopes you can still pass the variables without need for a global placeholder. Local variables are also referenced much more efficiently accessed than globals.

A few links:

[Sharing Variables in Python](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules.htm)

[Variable performance](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Local_Variables)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a = 'foo'
>>> def my_func(a='bar'):
...     return globals()['a']
...
>>> my_func()
'foo'
```