# Accessing global variable in local environment

Tags: python, scope, global-variables, global, local-variables

Consider this code:

```
Var='global'
def func():
     Var='local'
     #global Var
     print Var
```

I'm trying to print the global variable even though I have a local variable with the same name. 
However, when I use the keyword global, it gives me an error.

Is there a way to do this?

I would also appreciate an explanation of why global gives an error.

Comment: The simplest answer is don't use duplicated variable names, it leads to utter confusion, once your code gets to any length.

Comment: @Rolf, true. However, I'm just trying to explore all that is possible in python.

Comment: you said you get an error, but I am getting none. What error do you get?

Comment: To be more specific, I got a warning, not an error. It says: name 'Var' is assigned to before global declaration.   And then it prints local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) which is a built-in function. From documentation for [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals):

> Return a dictionary representing the current global symbol table. This is always the dictionary of the current module (inside a function or method, this is the module where it is defined, not the module from which it is called).

```
Var='global'

def func():
    Var='local'
    print(globals()['Var'])
```

---

Reply to your comment:

First try this:

```
Var='global'

def func():
    Var='local'
    global Var
    Var = 'Global'
    print(Var)
func()

print(Var)
```

Amazed? What's going on here is that Python assumes that any variable name that is assigned to, within a function, is local to that function unless explicitly told otherwise. If it is *only reading from a name*, and the **name doesn't exist locally**, it will try to look up the name in any containing scopes (e.g. the module's global scope). In your case there is a local variable `Var` with the same name as the global `Var`, so the global variable is shadowed. Since `Var` exists locally, it does not need to be looked up in any containing scopes, and thus the local variable is used. However, when you *change* the value of `Var` (using `global Var` statement) Python uses the global variable, which can be seen by printing `global Var` in the global scope. As a matter of fact, the `global` keyword is actually used to modify a global variable from any local sub-scope. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235973/modifying-global-variable-with-same-name-as-local-variable). Hope it is clear!

P.S.: I gathered the knowledge from [Jeff Shannon's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423668/3375713) answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is a brilliant idea!

Comment: Also, do you know why global does not work here? It is generally used to refer to a global variable inside a function, right?

Comment: @user93868 see the modified answer.