# How to access local variable after global keyword in python

Tags: python, scope

How to access a local variable with the same name as a global variable after the global keyword?

```
var = 0
def foo():
    var = 1
    global var
    var += 1

    #now how i do change the scope to the local variable without deleting var
```

Comment: *Why?* There's a lot wrong with this, but first, why were you trying to have a function use a local and a global with the same name in the first place?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235973/modifying-global-variable-with-same-name-as-local-variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the local variable a different name. `global` applies for the entirety of the function, you can't switch back and forth as you go. The best you could do is cheap hacks to access the global (`globals()['var']`) while leaving the name local, but don't do this. Use different names.