# Global variable exists still I get "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, global-variables, variable-assignment

The following python code gives an error. Why isn't it referencing the global variable a ?

```
a = 10

def b(x):
    if(x == True):
        a = 2
    return a

print(b(False))
```

The error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
File "<string>", line 6, in b
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're using a local variable that has the same name of the global one. This can help: [Modifying global variable with same name as local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10235973/modifying-global-variable-with-same-name-as-local-variable)

Edit: in fact, this seems to be working:

```
a = 10

def b(x):
    if(x == True):
        globals()['a'] = 2
    return a

print(b(False))
```

Comment: Yes, but my doubt was that python being a intepreter level language and the if condition being false, why is the a(local variable) inside if shadowing the global variable ?